# How can I set the php CLI version for Symfony2 without changing the code?

Tags: linux, symfony, php

My setup

- shared hosting
- no root access
- shell access
- symfony 2.1
- capifony for deployment (well, at least, that's the plan)

`build_bootstrap.php` uses

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

This is linked to the php4 cli in

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

PHP4 does of course not work. The php 5.3 cli is in

```
/usr/local/bin/php53
```

Is there a central place to tell Symfony 2.1 to change the env? Something with putenv? Export path in bash config files?

**Update:**

I am now using an alias for php in my bashrc as @thecatontheflat suggested.

Unfortunately Symfony brings its own logic where to look for the php binaries.
One option is to set PHP_PATH via putenv.
I added it both to app/console and app/autoload.php as both files are involved in the Capifony tasks

Comment: I don't think you can re-create the env in this kind of file (they are hard coded). Why don't you re-create the file with what you want (in update path inside) ?

Comment: I don't want to mess in 3rd party code (i.e. Symfony), because it will break after the next update (I will have forgotten the hack by then probably).

Comment: Why don't you set alias in your `bashrc` file for needed php?

Comment: @thecatontheflat This fixes part of the problem. :-) Unfortunately Symfony brings its own logic to determine the php binary (class /Component/Process/PhpExecutableFinder.php). This still gets the wrong version. I guess I have to put putenv()  into app/console.

Comment: Why putenv()? Wouldn't defining PHP_PATH in your .bashrc work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

add two settings to .bashrc/.bash_profile

```
alias php="/usr/local/bin/php53"
export PHP_PATH = "/usr/local/bin/php53"
```

and also set php_bin in Capifony's deploy.rb

```
set  :php_bin, " /usr/local/bin/php53"
```

Comment: You should remove the spaces before & after the =