# Artisan throws error when running command

Tags: symfony, laravel, laravel-artisan

I migrated my project (built in Laravel 5) to web server and when I tried to run artisan command I get this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Expetion\FatalErrorExeption]
syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR)
```

Does someone knows where is the problem?

Comment: what artisan command did you run?

Comment: @kdlcruz I tried php artisan list and my custom commands and none of them worked

Comment: try to do 'composer install' or 'composer update'

Comment: @kdlcruz I tried but same error pop ups when composer calls php artisan clear-complied

Comment: hmm, sorry I don't know anymore. Maybe try 'composer dump-autoload'.

Comment: @kdlcruz thank you for help. I tried to run command and error is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Namespace not supported probably you are in older version of php.
Check if your php version meets minimum system requirements

Should be 5.4+

Comment: My php version is 5.5.15

Comment: @jureispro but your php-cli version is not . check which php version is set for using via cli

Comment: How do you check php-cli version? I typed php-v in cmd and it says that:

PHP 5.5.15 (cli) .......

Comment: try this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347730/how-can-i-set-the-php-cli-version-for-symfony2-without-changing-the-code

Comment: I am using Windows Server :/